# Getting mmap() error when extracting 7z files

Tags: command-line, iphone, ios, command-line-tool, 7za

Every time I run `7z x test.7z`
Or any other command using 7z I get

```
Can't load '/usr/lib/p7zip/7z.dll' (dlopen(/usr/lib/p7zip/7z.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/lib/p7zip/7z.so: mmap() errno=22 at address=0x00629000, size=0x00009000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/p7zip/7z.so)

Can't load '/usr/lib/p7zip/Codecs/Rar29.so' (dlopen(/usr/lib/p7zip/Codecs/Rar29.so, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
/usr/lib/p7zip/Codecs/Rar29.so: mmap() errno=22 at address=0x000F1000, size=0x00001000 segment=__DATA in Segment::map() mapping /usr/lib/p7zip/Codecs/Rar29.so)
```

Is there any fix for this